# Why won't it let me ask this question?

Tags: discussion, bug, asking-questions

I just tried posting the following question on Stack Overflow:

**Why does gulp swallow a plugin error?**

But the form would not let me enter the question and told me that it was low quality or something along the lines. But the moment I put it this way it let it go through:

**Why does gulp swallow an error from a plugin?**

I guess grammatically the latter nicer. But I feel like this is a bit too nitpicky and just poses a hurdle from actually asking a question, which I at least feel is valid.

(I don't think putting a hard stop on minor grammatical tweaks is a good idea. Especially in light of StackOverflow trying to attract new programmers. This almost turned me down from asking.)

Comment: This isn't so much about grammar as it is about being descriptive. Of course, you can bypass the filter by adding more words - as you did - but I think you'll find that descriptive titles really help questions stand out and get answered.